# Change the top level's variables inside the called modules in verilog

Tags: global-variables, verilog, system-verilog

I've been trying to somehow implement the usage of global variable in Verilog.
Or alternatively, have a shared variable amongst the modules. Or even pass wires or register by reference (like the one we have in most high level languages like c++). Either of them will do the trick for me. But I couldn't implement any of them!

```
module topLevel(output [1:0] Output);

    wire[1:0] PC;

    sum s1();

    assign Output = PC;


endmodule


module sum();

    assign topLevel.PC = 2'b11;

endmodule
```

The code runs without any error but the value of  "PC" hasn't changed. What should I do?

Comment: is this simulation only or are you trying to synthesize (put on FPGA)? Are you allowed to use SystemVerilog?

Comment: @Greg Yes. I'm allowed to use SystemVerilog.

Comment: What did you mean that 'the value of PC did not change'? What is the value of it? Which simulator did you use? How did you check?

Comment: What do you get as `Output` value?

Answer (score 1):

With SystemVerilog you can declare the variable in a package. From there you can import the the content of the package (or the specific variable) to the module. Then use the variables names as though it was locally declare. Or you can not import and access the variable via its package scope. Example:

```
package my_pkg; // packages are globally accessible
  logic [1:0] PC; // static variable
endpackage

module topLevel(output [1:0] Output);
  import my_pkg::PC;  // or   import my_pkg::*;

  sum1 #(0,3)  s1();
  sum2 #(10,1) s2();
  assign Output = PC; // or   assign Output = my_pkg::PC;
endmodule

module sum1 #(parameter TIME=0, VALUE=0) ();
  import my_pkg::PC;          // or   import my_pkg::*;
  initial #(TIME) PC = VALUE;
endmodule
module sum2 #(parameter TIME=0, VALUE=0) ();
  initial #(TIME) my_pkg::PC = VALUE;
endmodule
```

Note that this works for simulation only and is generically NOT synthesizable.

To be synthesizeable or work with Verilog, you must add `PC` to the port lists throughout the hierarchy and ensure that there is only one active driver assigning `PC`. This means driven by one `assign` statement or updated by one `always` block.

Verilog and SystemVerilog are HDLs (Hardware Description Languages). A net (`wire`) represents a physical wire that has to be routed from one logic gate's output to the inputs of other logic gates. Any type of referencing support in the HDL language was added only to be used by the test-bench in simulations.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code in VCS and the `PC` value is properly being changed.

Please see the following.

```
module topLevel(output [1:0] Output);
  wire[1:0] PC;

  sum s1();

  assign Output = PC;

  initial
    $monitor ("PC - %0b", PC);
endmodule

module sum();
  assign topLevel.PC = 2'b11;
endmodule

// Output - 
PC - 11
```

However I am not sure about synthesizability of the following code.

**Inside a module, you should always access the internal nets & ports only.**

So in the above design, you can connect `Output` net to the ports of the `sum` module like the following.

```
module topLevel(output [1:0] Output);
  wire[1:0] PC;

  sum s1(PC);

  assign Output = PC;
endmodule

module sum(output [1:0] x);
  assign x = 2'b11;
endmodule
```